# How to stop VoiceOver announcement for UISegmentedControl?

Tags: ios, accessibility

My app has a `UISegmentedControl` that contains two buttons. I'm able to access each button's accessibility fields; the problem I'm having is that for subviews of a segmented control, VoiceOver reads out the subview's accessibility properties and then announces the view's position within the segmented control, so the VoiceOver announcement for the first button is "Previous message. Button. One of two." and for the second button it's "Next message. Button. Two of two."

How can I prevent the last part of these announcements (the "one of two" and "two of two" parts), which have no real meaning to VoiceOver users?

Comment: Those position announcements are part of the standard for `UISegmentedController`. They do have a real meaning. This lets the person know that the buttons are related and not separate. Without the "One of Two", they would appear as individual buttons to the visually impaired, instead of the "radio buttons" that they really are.

Comment: @rmaddy: it's not that they have no meaning. This segmented controller is on a toolbar that contains other buttons that are not part of the segmented controller. There's nothing special about these two buttons (logically, they are not radio buttons), but they were implemented as a segmented control long before we were worried about accessibility. I want these buttons to be announced the same way as all the others, to prevent confusion.

Comment: The two button are special. The two buttons in a segmented control are mutually exclusive. Only one can be selected at a time. That is the purpose of the "One of Two", "Two of Two" part of the announcement. A standalone button doesn't need this. Removing that part of the announcement will cause more confusion to voice over users. They need to be made aware that the buttons are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @rmaddy: but the buttons here are *not* mutually exclusive, and in fact they're not "selectable" at all. They're just "previous" and "next" buttons.

Comment: OK, then the segmented control is momentary. Now your request makes a bit more sense. I guess Apple still feels the extra part of the announcement makes sense. File an enhancement request with Apple that momentary segmented controls shouldn't add the extra part of the announcement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `accessibilityTraits` property of `UISegmentedControl`'s subviews to `UIAccessibilityTraitNone` to disable "Tab X of Y" part of the VoiceOver:

```
    for (UIView *thisView in self.segmentedControl.subviews) {
        [thisView setAccessibilityTraits:UIAccessibilityTraitNone];
    }
```

Comment: That was the trick, thanks. A bit of a pain, though, since setting the buttons to UIAccessibilityTraitNone means they're not announced as buttons and their enabled/disabled state is ignored as well, so I just added those properties to the accessibilityLabel programmatically (e.g. "Dimmed. Previous email. Button."

Comment: I didn't investigate in detail, but I believe some other combination of UIAccessibilityTraits could give you the desired behaviour without disabling the useful part.

Comment: Well, the most basic thing I need is for it to announce itself as "Button", since all the other buttons do. But if I just set the two subviews to UIAccessibilityTraitButton, the segmented control does its "1 of 2" thing. No big deal - enjoy your bounty.

Comment: I tried on 5.1 and after setting UIAccessibilityTraitButton (by modifying the code above) it works, adding "Button" but not "1 of 2". Can you share more info about your exact setup?

Comment: I'm running on iOS 6.0.1. Maybe they changed this behavior between 5 and 6.